# How do I solve a linear system with two variables and three equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

To be specific here is the system:

$$x-2y=0 \tag{1}$$
$$x-2(k+2)y=0 \tag{2}$$
$$x-(k+3)y=-k \tag{3}$$

I have already solved it for equations $(1)$ and $(2)$... what should I do with the 3rd equation?

Just to make sure everything goes well here is my method:

$D=-2(k+2)$ and $D_x=D_y=0$

If $k=-2$ then $D=0$ so there are indefinite solutions.
If $k\not=-2$ then $D\not=0$ so the solution is $(0,0)$

Answer (score 0):

From first equation $x=2y$. Substitute it into 2 and 3:
$$
2y-2(k+2)y=0,\\
2y-y(k+3)=-k,
$$
or
$$
y(k+1)=0,\\
y(k+1) = -k
$$
If $k\ne 0$, there are no solutions. If $k=0$ then $y=0$ and $x=0$.

Comment: So you are just combining the first equation to the other two...This way you are left with another overdetermined system. May I add up two equations so that I'm left with 2?

Answer (score 0):

Having the unknowns $x$ and $y$ one can write this system of linear equations as
$$
A u = b \iff \\
\left[
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & -2 & 0 \\
1 & -2(k+2) & 0 \\
1 & -(k+3) & -k
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & -2k-2 & 0 \\
0 & -k-1 & -k
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & k+1 & 0 \\
0 & k+1 & k
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & k+1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & k
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & k
\end{array}
\right]
$$
So after some transformations we notice that only $x = y = 0$ for $k=0$ is possible as solution.